# VMWare Workstation cannot connect to parallel port after upgrade

Tags: vmware-workstation

After upgrading VMWare Workstation the physical parallel ports are no longer available. I have uninstalled and reinstalled VMWare, on running it as administrator I get the following error when trying to connect:

```
Cannot open VMparport driver for LPT3: The system cannot find the file specified

Failed to connect virtual device 'parallel0'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get things back up and running. I believe it may be an issue with version 12.5 of Workstation Player. The consistent thing to identify whether the parallel port is installed is the presence of windows\system32\drivers\VMparport.sys. Simply uninstalling and reinstalling did not work. The steps I used are as follows:

```
1) Uninstall VMWare Player
2) Remove all configurations using VMWare-player-12.5.xxx.exe /clean
3) Open Device Manager, Uninstall the parallel port
4) Restart computer
5) Verify the LPT port exists in the device manager
6) Install VMWare Player v12.1.xxx. Do not enable the enhanced keyboard driver. 
7) Verify presence of windows\system32\drivers\VMparport.sys
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found this fast solution, which is awaiting a patch from VMware.

You add the VMparport service to the Windows registry using the following text - put it in a file and save with a .reg extension, then open the file.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\VMparport]
"DisplayName"="VMware VMparport"
"Description"="VMware Parallel Port Driver."
"Type"=dword:00000001
"Start"=dword:00000002
"ErrorControl"=dword:00000001
"ImagePath"=hex(2):5c,00,3f,00,3f,00,5c,00,43,00,3a,00,5c,00,57,00,49,00,4e,00,44,00,4f,00,57,00,53,00,5c,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,74,00,65,00,6d,00,33,00,32,00,5c,00,64,00,72,00,69,00,76,00,65,00,72,00,73,00,5c,00,56,00,4d,00,70,00,61,00,72,00,70,00,6f,00,72,00,74,00,2e,00,73,00,79,00,73,00,00,00
"Group"="Extended base"
```

Then restart the system.